# What is the correct (best) way to set the value of cv::Scalar to a pixel in a cv::Mat in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `cv::Mat` object,

```
cv::Mat _a ...
```

... and a `cv::Scalar` object,

```
cv::Scalar _b ...
```

What is the correct (best) way to set the value of `_b` to a pixel (in the position (x, y)) in `_a` ?

Note that the object `_a` can have 1, 2, 3, 4 channels, but the code should work in all cases, that is:

- when `_a` have 1 channel the first element of `_b` should be assigned in the respective position
- when `_a` have 2 channel the first element of `_b` should be assigned to the first channel and the second element of _b should be assigned to the second channel, both in the respective position
- (....)

Comment: You can use `Mat::at<Vec4>` function and than iterate from 0 to `Mat::channels-1` over the result creating/assigning a `Scalar`

Comment: @Simson, but you have to notice that Vec4 is not a type from opencv, in this case, the avaliable types are Vec4b, Vec4d, Vec4f, Vec4i, Vec4s and Vec4w. If the correct type is not known in advance (as is in this case) we could get an error.

Comment: You can get the type of each channel through [Mat::depth](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth). Then you can switch the vec type accordingly. Maybe this is not very nice, but it should work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::Mat` has an overloaded [`operator=`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-operator) which takes a `cv::Scalar`. This has the exact behavior you desire. Unfortunately, there isn't a direct way to assign `Scalar` to pixel values. However, you can create a Region of Interest containing the single pixel at the coordinates `(x, y)` and assign the `Scalar` to that:

```
cv::Mat a; // contains data
cv::Scalar b(1,2,3,4);

cv::Range xr(x, x + 1);
cv::Range yr(y, y + 1);
a(xr, yr) = b;
```

Comment: No, sorry, I want to set the value for only one pixel, that is, the value of an image at a position (x,y).

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot !!, I am already tried a lot, but a can not get a clean solution ... That's why I asking for the best way to do it.

Comment: Maybe a combination of both ... But a concise way is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very nice or concise but you can switch the [possible types](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth) of the `Mat` and iterate over the channels of the `Mat` to create/assign the `Scalar`. Something like this:

```
void getPixel(Mat m, int x, int y, Scalar &pixel) {
    switch (m.depth()) {
    case 0:
        for (size_t i =  0; i < m.channels(); ++i) pixel[i] = m.at<uchar>(x, y);
        break;
    case 1:
        for (size_t i =  0; i < m.channels(); ++i) pixel[i] = m.at<char>(x, y);
        break;
    case 2:
        for (size_t i =  0; i < m.channels(); ++i) pixel[i] = m.at<ushort>(x, y);
        break;
    case 3:
        for (size_t i =  0; i < m.channels(); ++i) pixel[i] = m.at<short>(x, y);
        break;
    case 4:
        for (size_t i =  0; i < m.channels(); ++i) pixel[i] = m.at<long>(x, y);
        break;
    case 5:
        for (size_t i =  0; i < m.channels(); ++i) pixel[i] = m.at<float>(x, y);
        break;
    case 6:
        for (size_t i =  0; i < m.channels(); ++i) pixel[i] = m.at<double>(x, y);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the .at function from opencv. Its slow when you iterate through a big picture. 
Get some structs ready for example for RGB images:

```
 #pragma pack(push, 2)
  struct RGB {        //members are in "bgr" order!
     uchar blue;
     uchar green;
     uchar red;  };
```

And then create a pointer to the scanline of the image like this:

```
RGB& rgb = image.ptr<RGB>(y)[x]; //y = row, x = col
```

You can then assign the values like this:

```
cv::Scalar(image.ptr<RGB>(y)[x].value[0], image.ptr<RGB>(y)[x].value[1], image.ptr<RGB>(y)[x].value[2]);
```